# Detect if flash is enabled in the browser

Tags: php, flash, joomla

I have this Joomla site that displays if the cookies, javascript and flash are enabled or not. I've figured out the cookies and javascript part but not on the flash part. So can someone help me how to do this?

Comment: What technology are you restricted to? Will you use JQuery? There are plugins for JQuery that do what you're after.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998245/how-can-i-detect-if-flash-is-installed-and-if-not-display-a-hidden-div-that-inf

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142788/how-can-i-detect-if-flash-player-is-disabled-in-a-browser-using-javascript