# Check what most recent version of flash is? To see if flash disable by browser

Tags: flash, adobe

**Is there an Adobe endpoint I can ping that will respond with the current version number?**

My use-case:

On the page I have a flash video player, and if flash is out of date I want to reinitialize the player with html5 rather than force the user to download the most up-to-date flash version to see the content.

With swfobject, one can do swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion('14.0') and see if the browser's flash version is equal to or greater than some number. But this is not future-proof. Someday the browser will require a greater number than I've just hardcoded.

Possible alternative solution: some way to query the browser to see what version of flash it requires to not display the "Flash out of date" widget.

I have tried the getURL solution from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142788/how-can-i-detect-if-flash-player-is-disabled-in-a-browser-using-javascript?s=f5ef1332f7f24094a1a15ec94372c5c8) but I couldn't get any javascript to execute that way. There may be flash security requirements that no longer make that solution possible.